# What are the pitfalls of using box-sizing: border-box?

Tags: css, border-box

I was recently looking at the box-sizing property again. I feel like border-box is actually a more appropriate model. I want my boxes to include the padding and border without needing to account for it every time in the width calculation, which is not really possible when using 100% width.

So the question is what are the pitfalls? Why should I not use border-box?

Comment: It's too bad this question was closed.  I came here specifically looking for such pitfalls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only pifall I can think of it's that is not supported by IE7&8, on IE9 works fine

Comment: It is supported in IE8 http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing